# Performance of Static website on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform, website, static-content, google-cloud-storage

I have some low-traffic static websites to host. As an alternative to hosting them on my own or self-managed web servers (eg AWS, Google Cloud, or Digial Ocean machines running Apache or Nginx), I'm considering using Google Cloud Storage:

- [it seems to support that use case pretty well](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website)
- it's way cheaper: eg if I serve 1K visitors at 1Mb of data each, that's 1GB of data served + 1MB of data hosted = $0.026 (per GB per month) * $0.001 (GB hosted) = $0.00026 per month. Even if I'm off with a factor of 1000 in my calculations, it's still <1$ ([see pricing calculator on the right hand side](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#id=08440562-9af4-483d-ac82-30079eb93062)).

The only thing I wonder about is performance, hence my question:

**Has anybody hosted static websites with Google Cloud Store and can share feedback or knows some I can test the speed of?**

Comment: If you're worried about performance, put [their CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/) in front of it.

Comment: True, but if cloud storage performance is good enough, it's 1 less infrastructure piece to deal with, hence why still interested in finding out about performance of cloud storage itself.

Comment: Well, you'll need to define "good enough" then.

Comment: Eventually yes, right now I'm trying to collect some figures. Then I can compare with other options and decide. Eg if it's 10% slower than hosting it myself, but virtually costs nothing, I take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this site](https://www.savjee.be/2017/10/Static-website-hosting-who-is-fastest/) that shows some numbers for response times of Google Cloud Storage-hosted static website. Apart from that, if you want to compare managed web service hosting option and GCS, why not just testing that? You can deploy the same website in [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview#app-engine) and also host it in [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/web-serving-overview#static-site) to make some direct comparison when it comes to latency, throughput or concurrent requests.